# Bootstrap 3.0.3 glyphicons displaying emoticons on iOS 7

Tags: ios, twitter-bootstrap, emoticons, glyphicons

I use Bootstrap 3.0.3 glyphicons. All is ok on desktop browsers and on Android devices. My problem is about Apple devices (tested on iPhone and iPad running iOS7).

The glyphicons look like emoticons. I've found some issues but not answering my problem.

Here is the link to view the screenshot : http://www.fredericblancheton.fr/imgdisallow/image.png

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Do you have this line in the `<head>` part? `<meta charset="utf-8">`

Comment: Yes the meta charset utf-8 is included...

Comment: May be its a conflict between Glyphicons font version and the version of Bootstrap. Ensure that they were both from the same release (3.0.3)

Comment: Yes. I've checked as well but still the same.

Comment: Problem solved : the path (@icon-font-path) in the variable.less file was wrong. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem, but only when another font was included via `font-face` inside the stylesheet. It seems that mobile safari or safari in general has a very short timeout for loading fonts which are included via `font-face` syntax.

I had to remove the font from the main stylesheet and add the `font-face` syntax directly in the sites header using `<style></style>` syntax. Weird.

Another approach is illustrated over at filamentgroup, which are using the Data-URI syntax for the font and loading these asynchronously via javascript. This should also trick the browser to wait longer.
-> http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/font-loading.html

Answer (score 1):

We've seen the same problem in our app - it's totally bizarre. It happens when the user has installed an old Emoji app ("Emoji Free!", which I can no longer find in the app store).

The only solution was to get the user to uninstall the app.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered same issue and resolved it by removing woff2 font file from @font-face. It seems iOS doesn't support woff2.

**[Updated 2016-03-02]**
Fix above turns out just matter of luck (timing?).
@rofflox 's answer which seems to be more promising and it works for me.

Comment: I had this problem and the solution was remove the woff and the woff2, thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

I just tried the solutions above and none of them worked for me. It turned out that:

1. I had updated bootstrap to 3.3.6 css
2. I didn't update the font files that came with it

Getting the latest version of the font files fixed my issue with the unwanted emojis.

Answer (score 0):

I started getting this error today using Pulsar for Salesforce, I turned out that my FE DEV had included references to Fonts and forgotten to update the static resources with the new fonts! In case that helps someone.