# Bootstrap 3 Glyphicons on IOS display something else

Tags: ios, cordova, twitter-bootstrap-3, glyphicons

I'm new to phonegap/cordova.  I tried writing a small app using bootstrap 3, and running "cordova serve" produces expected results on browsers.  However, running "cordova emulate ios" as well as running the resulting app on an actual iPhone produces weird results from the glyphicons.

I think the OP here ([Bootstrap 3.0.3 glyphicons displaying emoticons on iOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20879432/bootstrap-3-0-3-glyphicons-displaying-emoticons-on-ios-7)) had a similar problem, and seemed to have found a solution, but did not elaborate.  Unfortunately, I have too few reps to comment on his question to ask him what he did specifically.

[Image is as expected in a browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgVxa.jpg).

[Weird result in ios simulator/acutal phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1FHV.jpg).

Hope someone could help.

Thanks!
=)