# Bootstrap glyphicons show wrong icon

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

I have seen this happen while developing my site, sometimes my glyphicons don't render correctly and show different icons.  I have recently got some reports of my shopping cart and search button showing up as a hammer and lips. I am using bootstrap v3.3.4 and have the fonts stored on my server with an absolute path.  I have seen this happen in FireFox and just got a mobile report in Safari.  Anyone ever have this issue or maybe an idea why it happens?

[image]

I am going to add that when I remember seeing this I refreshed the page or cleared my cache and it fixed the problem. But my client wants a better answer than it just happens refresh the page.

Comment: I'm not sure why this happens but you could try removing the hammer and lips from the glyphicons directory on your server.

Comment: So, the hammer and lips you're seeing aren't valid bootstrap icons, they're emojis. I found [this issue](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/13488) but I'm not sure how to guide you further. Does this issue only pop-up on Apple devices?

Comment: There may be an answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20879432/bootstrap-3-0-3-glyphicons-displaying-emoticons-on-ios-7) as well (see comments).

Comment: This happened on an iphone 5 in safari and happened on windows in FireFox.

Comment: Why you don't try a css trace in FireFox?

Comment: If glyficon icons is inconsistent at the moment, then use font awesome icons for quick fix. It seems your issue is quite strange.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue with a project I was working on.  My understanding is that the platforms own icons/emojis are taking prefrence over your own because they share the same names.  As a work around I changed my naming convention with an obscure prefix.  Been trouble free ever since.  If you are like me and weren't sure how to go about this I used [Fontastic Me Font Icon Maker](http://fontastic.me/) as a starting point.  Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the my solution:
In _variables.scss (or css) find the line with icon font path:

$icon-font-path: if($bootstrap-sass-asset-helper, "bootstrap/", "**../**../fonts/bootstrap/") !default;

In my case, the problem was in the wrong path to fonts/bootstrap (the glyphicons are here). To fix the problem just remove one "../" from there. Your code should be something like this:

$icon-font-path: if($bootstrap-sass-asset-helper, "bootstrap/", "**../fonts/bootstrap/**") !default;

Hope it helps.

Comment: This was my issue. I installed bootstrap using bower, modified bootstrap.less and variable.less and created a site.less file to combine and import them in to site.css, the issue is the "../font/" in variable.less is compiled inside glyphicons.less to /bower_components/bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2, which didn't work when I deployed it because the bower folder isn't deployed.

Comment: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/13488
For more options and information...

Answer (score 1):

(Putting this here for anyone searching in future, highlighting the answer in [the link](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/13488) posted by Tony in a comment to the original question.)

If you're using an ad blocker on iOS, you will see this issue - emoji replacing the glyphicons (e.g. monkey face replaces calendar). I don't have a solution other than disabling the ad blocker.

BTW a similar thing happens with font-awesome but instead of showing emoji, the icons just don't appear. This is not great but definitely better!